# Bootstrap Icon is not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have added a a button and Styled it using Bootstrap but the icon(Font) of the button is not as per the styling.I am not able to figure out what is missing in the Markup..Here is the HTML..

```
<button class="btn-u btn-u-xs btn-brd btn-brd-hover" type="button" title="Add New" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive" onclick="">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Add New</span>
</button>
```

Please help me to resolve this .Thanks

Comment: can you create plunker for it

Comment: @Arvaan Here is the Link http://embed.plnkr.co/s3c94Y50p6q43VbdK7cj/preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't include the fa fa icons. put this in your head and you're good to go

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Well I added the link shared by downloading and then referring in my application but now i am, getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Static File '/Assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2' not found)` error on console

Comment: this error means the file doesn;t exist or your path isn;t correct. Just inlcude the <link> put it in your <head> and you can use the fa fa

Comment: @Could you please tell me the CDN for `fontawesome-webfont.woff2` font

Comment: Okay.Thanks I got the fonts and i can see it on page but Now the CSS is not getting applied..Any Suggestions for that ..Thanks in advance...